# podofocrop doesn't create new PDF

Tags: pdf, podofo

I did `apt-get install ghostscript libpodofo-utils` in Ubuntu and then `podofocrop orig.pdf new.pdf 245.52 0.0 1290.48 1437.12` but new.pdf is not generated. Here's the output that libpodofo gives me:

```
Usage: podofocrop input.pdf output.pdf
       This tool will crop all pages.
       It requires ghostscript to be in your PATH

PoDoFo Version: 0.9.6
```

`apt-get install ghostscript` did install it in my PATH. I got my PATH by doing `echo $PATH and then I looked in each of the directories in my PATH and found it in /usr/bin/ghostscript. So it looks like that requirement is met and yet no output.pdf got produced.

Any ideas?